# What does the term 'epitope mapping' mean?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, bioinformatics, immunology

Epitope mapping means identifying the binding site of antibodies on the target antigen. This means that the site to be identified is part of the antigen and not antibody, am I right?

Comment: yes.. you are right. Why the confusion :)

Comment: No, just wanted to make sure, actually I am reading immunoinformatics for my phd, and hence i should have crystal clear idea about the things i study. So thats y asked this question. It is not homework. its discussion

Comment: i know it is not a "homework" homework.. by homework we mean something that can easily be looked up.

Comment: yes,, things can be looked up, but sometimes understanding is a bit difficult more so becoz i havnt touched biology in the past 7 years